# Validation of modeling step of PLS

Tags: regression, prediction, partial-least-squares

How can i validate the modeling step of my dataset with PLS regression?

In other words can i calculate an **X_hat** and **Y_hat** using the modeling factors (**T,P,Q,U,B,W**) and compare it with the original **X** and **Y**. I'm using the algorithm PLS2.

Answer (score 0):

By using the PLS Regression you can follow this steps:

1. Apply the algorithm by using a validation method (i recommend the full cross validation);
2. Select the number of latent variables that the validation gives to you;
3. Re-run the pls algorithm with the number of latent variables in step 2 and re-apply the cross validation.

With this 3 steps you can obtain an $\hat{y}$ but the $X$ now is the result of the combination of the old variables, the Score Matrix.
Basically you can only compare the original $y$ with the new $\hat{y}$, because of the nature of the latent variables that you select.

Comment: I think the original poster wants an answer something like this:
X = TP' + error